# SSAS - scoping on entire dimension

Tags: ssas

Is there a way, in Calculations SSAS, to scope an entire dimension without precision on which attribute and member?

Example on File dimension, having many attributes and members.

```
Scope 
 ( 
    [File]
 ) ;   

   This =1;   
End Scope ;
```

Comment: Can you explain a little further what numbers you get now and what you hope to get after the scope statement? Do you want the scope statement to impact other dimensions?

Comment: I haven`t got any numbers yet, still working on the design, but the idea is that the default member will apply even if it is not part of the result and other attributes of the same dimension are used. today, if other attributes are used, the default member does not apply if that particular attribute is not selected as part of the result.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its clear what you trying to achieve here. But...

I think what you are trying to do is more inline with setting a default member on a dimension. This can be done using the following code:

```
ALTER
  CUBE CURRENTCUBE
    UPDATE DIMENSION [<<dim name here>>],
      DEFAULT_MEMBER = [<<dim name here>>].[<<hierarchy name here>>].&[1];
```

If you are setting the scope of a measure to be forced on a particular dimension attribute then you would use the scope on the measure/named set.

Answer (score 0):

If you do such a thing, it would be not working as you expect. If you will see the same value independent of dimension member, it would be as if that dimension is not at all connected to the measure group. Also if you do that also for the dimension ALL member, then it would mean that whole cube will have the exact same value independent of any dimension/member chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SCOPE` for the lowest key level may help.

I've tested on timeline dimension with the key on `REPORT DATE ID` field:
[image: Dimension Structure]

And code in calculations:

```
SCOPE([Report Date].[REPORT DATE ID].Members);
THIS=1;
END SCOPE;
```

Any selected level of any hierarchy shows this result.
[image: SCOPE Result]

Hope this helps.